# Django-wiki installed but root article throws global flag error

Tags: django, django-wiki

I have installed Django-wiki in a fresh virtual Django install.  My initial page comes up, the site allows for user registration.  Everything looks well until I enter my first Root article.

I have kept it rudimentary with a title "Test" and the body just a simple "Hello" but when I save I get this error:

error at /
global flags not at the start of the expression at position 9
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://xxxxxxx.preprod.xxxx:8000/
Django Version: 4.0.8
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:
global flags not at the start of the expression at position 9
Exception Location: C:\python\Lib\re_parser.py, line 841, in _parse
Python Executable:  C:\daas_django_apps\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0

Error during template rendering
In template C:\daas_django_apps\env\Lib\site-packages\wiki\templates\wiki\view.html, error at line 7

Line 7 is:

> 

```
  {% wiki_render article %}
```

I have tried checking all my configuration and it seems ok and matches Django-Wiki installation example.  Tried changing user ownership of the article and creating a group for viewing but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the use of inline global flags (eg: `(?im)`) in two regular expressions are now raising an exception, instead of a warning before 3.11 (https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91222).

A fix has been merged on the main branch and it will be released soon if there are no other issues with 3.11.

See https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki/pull/1243 for more details.